# ElasticSearch 7.2.0 - nodes not connecting to each other in a cluster mode

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

I did installation of Elsatic search this way. Single node works but Cluster does NOT work (2 nodes can not establish connection).

What is missing please?

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.2.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

tar -xzf elasticsearch-7.2.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
cd elasticsearch-7.2.0/ 


# Set config for Elastic Search (in ./config/elasticsearch.yml)

# Master:
echo "" >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "xpack.security.enabled: true" >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "cluster.name: es-int"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "node.name: node-1"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "path.data: /tmp/elasticsearch.data"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "path.logs: /tmp/elasticsearch.log"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "network.host: 0.0.0.0"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo 'discovery.seed_hosts: ["master-ip", "slave-ip" ]'  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo 'cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master-ip"]'  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "http.port: 9200"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "transport.host: localhost"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "transport.tcp.port: 9300"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml

# Slave:
echo "" >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "xpack.security.enabled: true" >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "cluster.name: es-int"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "node.name: node-2"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "path.data: /tmp/elasticsearch.data"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "path.logs: /tmp/elasticsearch.log"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "network.host: 0.0.0.0"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "http.port: 9200"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo 'discovery.seed_hosts: ["master-ip", "slave-ip" ]'  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo 'cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master-ip"]'  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "transport.host: localhost"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml
echo "transport.tcp.port: 9300"  >> ./config/elasticsearch.yml

./bin/elasticsearch
```

Error:

```
[WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [node-1] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [master-ip] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered []; discovery will continue using [master-ip:9300, slave-ip:9300] from hosts providers and [{node-1}{Auontlf87A}{hJQJg9JD-IA}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}{ml.machine_memory=8201650176, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
```

Comment: Are you starting both the instances on local machine?

Comment: No, starting on 2 different Rhel Linux servers..

Comment: @Joe were u able to resolve the issue

Comment: No - still have issue..

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it has something to do with [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/system-config.html#dev-vs-prod). Have you tried setting the `network.host` ips to the actual master-ip and slave-ip addresses?

*edit*: Link is probably not relevant here after all. Instead, set `node.master: true` to allow for a node to be elected as master node.

*edit2*: Probably not it as well, since this is the default. I'm at a loss unfortunately

Comment: Yeah on second thought my link is probably not that relevant since you're not actually getting exceptions. A master node needs to have `node.master: true`, that seems to be missing?

Comment: Where do you get that info (just curious) since I do not know the correct one.. Does slave needs to have `node.slave: true` as well?

Comment: No, you don't have to set slave at all. A node can either be master, data or ingest (or a combination of these). See also the [node documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html)

*edit*: Once again, I'm probably off the mark. I just noticed master is true per default, so this probably won't be it. Unfortunately I'm at a loss then.